# Git/Github: How to sync local files with most up to date online files?

Tags: git, version-control, github, version, versioning

My local files are synchronised with Github, but I want to make changes on the README online. After I made this changes, how do I update my local file?

**OBS:** I'm new to Git and also to Git Hub. I've googled for this, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pull the code again from Github.

Assuming your branch is `master` and the remote is `origin` (that's usually the default)

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: @ramaismon: feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer if it has helped you. This helps other users of the site know that the question has been answered.

Comment: @bernie Yeah, I was just waiting the minimum time to accept an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a file online is similar to making a change on a different computer and pushing it to the remote repository.

If you want to sync changes from remote repository to a local repository you should use `git pull`.